# socket.io server firing disconnect every other time and then double fires

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I open 10 windows. I have 5 pairs of clients connected. I close all the windows 1 by 1. Only every other disconnection is fired and for each of those they double fire.

What could cause this??

```
 var fs = require( 'fs' );
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var servIO = require('https').createServer({ 
key: fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('fullchain.pem') 
},app);
var serv = require('http').Server(app);


app.get('//',function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});
app.use('/client',express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

serv.listen(8001);
servIO.listen(8002);
console.log("Server started.");
var SOCKET_LIST = {};

var io = require('socket.io')(servIO,{});
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.id = uniqueNumber();
    socket.x = 0;
    socket.y = 0;
    socket.opponent = "";
    socket.number = "" + Math.floor(10 * uniqueNumber());
    SOCKET_LIST[socket.id] = socket;

    for(var ii in SOCKET_LIST){
        var sk = SOCKET_LIST[ii];

        if(sk.opponent == "" && sk.id !== socket.id)
        {

            var joinedopponant = true;
            SOCKET_LIST[sk.id].opponent = socket.id;
            SOCKET_LIST[socket.id].opponent = sk.id;
            console.log('user ' + SOCKET_LIST[sk.id].opponent + ' joined user ' + SOCKET_LIST[socket.id].opponent);

            var socket = SOCKET_LIST[sk.id];
            socket.emit('UserJoinedYou', socket.id);
            break;
        }
    }

     if(!joinedopponant)
     {
            var socket = SOCKET_LIST[socket.id];
            var pack = [];
            pack.push({
            waiting:true
            });  
            socket.emit('waiting', pack);
            console.log('user ' + socket.id + ' waiting');

     }

    socket.on('disconnect',function()
    {

        console.log(socket.id + ' has left');
        delete SOCKET_LIST[socket.id];
        /*
        var opponent = SOCKET_LIST[socket.id].opponent;
        var socket = SOCKET_LIST[opponent];
        socket.emit('UserDisConnect', 'User Left');
        SOCKET_LIST[opponent].opponent = "";
        console.log('user ' + opponentp + ' waiting');

        */

    });

    function uniqueNumber() {
    var date = Date.now();

    // If created at same millisecond as previous
    if (date <= uniqueNumber.previous) {
        date = ++uniqueNumber.previous;
    } else {
        uniqueNumber.previous = date;
    }

    return date;
    }


uniqueNumber.previous = 0;


});
```

Console output is this:

- 1521070467800 has left
- 1521070467800 has left
- 1521070467801 has left
- 1521070467801 has left
- 1521070467802 has left
- 1521070467802 has left
- 1521070467803 has left
- 1521070467803 has left
- 1521070467804 has left
- 1521070467804 has left

### Edit

After some debugging it seems that if this code block is in there it happens and if it isn't then it doesn't happen. So the cause is somewhere in here

```
 for(var ii in SOCKET_LIST){
        var sk = SOCKET_LIST[ii];

        if(sk.opponent == "" && sk.id !== socket.id)
        {

            var joinedopponant = true;
            SOCKET_LIST[sk.id].opponent = socket.id;
            SOCKET_LIST[socket.id].opponent = sk.id;
            console.log(sk.id + ' - ' + socket.id);
            console.log(SOCKET_LIST[sk.id].opponent + ' - ' + SOCKET_LIST[socket.id].opponent);
            console.log('user ' + SOCKET_LIST[sk.id].opponent + ' joined user ' + SOCKET_LIST[socket.id].opponent);

            var socket = SOCKET_LIST[sk.id];
            socket.emit('UserJoinedYou', socket.id);

        }
    }
```

It doesn't make sense to me why this code would have any effect in the event of a disconnection?

### Edit

This is the line that causes the problem.

```
SOCKET_LIST[socket.id].opponent = sk.id;
```

If I comment this line out, the disconnect fires every time and correctly. If I un-comment this line then it does what I have described above.

Comment: You very well may be messing up some internal housekeeping for socket.io when you assign your own value to `socket.id`.  If you want your own id, then use a different, non-conflicting property name.  You can use `.myId` or `._id` or anything that isn't already in use.  Or, you can just use the `socket.id` that socket.io already created for you (just don't overwrite `socket.id` with something else).

Comment: Ok changed that so it doesn't write the id and just uses the preset one. Still does the same thing

Comment: Why are you using `.once()` here `socket.once('disconnect',function()...)` instead of `.on()`?

Comment: @jfriend00 to cut a long story short... its changed back to on now. Still does the same thing. aghhhh help me!

Comment: Change `var socket` to some other name in the code that is causing the problem.  It is conflicting with the `socket` argument to the `io.on('connect', function(socket) ...)`.  This is because of variable hoisting.  Or, use `let socket` instead or `var socket` so it's block-scoped.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `var socket` to some other name in the code that is causing the problem.

It is conflicting with the socket argument to the

```
io.on('connect', function(socket) ...)
```

This is because of variable hoisting as is similar to:

```
io.on('connect', function(socket) {
    var socket;
    // can't access the desired socket parameter here
});
```

Or, you can also use `let socket` instead of `var socket` so it's block-scoped and doesn't interfere.

Comment: That was hard to spot.  This is one of many reasons to stop using `var` and only use `const` and `let` which are both block scoped so this would not have happened.

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
var socket  = SOCKET_LIST[sk.id];
```

variable to;

```
var skup = SOCKET_LIST[sk.id];
```